# iOS 12-only QuartzCore crash on com.apple.coremedia.player.async

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I've got a crash report on `QuartzCore`, **which seems to only happened on iOS 12**. It crashed on `com.apple.coremedia.player.async`.

I've found several similar reports on [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109515), but there is no solution provided yet.

Here is the full stack trace (iOS 12.0.1) :

```
Crashed: com.apple.coremedia.player.async.0x283b5c240
0  QuartzCore                     0x18f8ad578 X::Ref<CA::Shape>::operator=(CA::Shape*) + 20
1  QuartzCore                     0x18f8ad434 CABackingStoreGetFrontTexture(CABackingStore*, CGColorSpace*) + 348
2  QuartzCore                     0x18f8ad2a8 CABackingStoreRetainFrontTexture + 48
3  QuartzCore                     0x18f9d4e54 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) _copyRenderLayer:layerFlags:commitFlags:] + 676
4  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da9e4 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 448
5  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
6  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
7  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
8  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
9  QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
10 QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
11 QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
12 QuartzCore                     0x18f9da928 CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
13 QuartzCore                     0x18f92e528 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 3240
14 QuartzCore                     0x18f95c2f4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 608
15 MediaToolbox                   0x18fe4d300 remoteXPCPlayer_setClientVideoLayerArray + 1284
16 MediaToolbox                   0x18fe4c598 remoteXPCPlayer_SetProperty + 340
17 MediaToolbox                   0x18fdb362c playerasync_runOneCommand + 1876
18 MediaToolbox                   0x18fdb63d0 playerasync_runAsynchronousCommandOnQueue + 172
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ae20484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18adc7c18 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x18adc8794 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 484
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x18adcfa60 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x18adcf7e0 _dispatch_worker_thread + 284
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18b0012fc _pthread_body + 128
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18b00125c _pthread_start + 48
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18b004d08 thread_start + 4
```

I have absolutely no clue to determine where it could come from. The crash log suggests that it could come from video, and my app contains a Youtube Player, so it may be related.

Does anybody have an idea ? Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: I am also getting the same crash, on the device I was not able to reproduce it but I see in my Fabric/Crashlytics Dashboard. This crash introduced in iOS 12

Comment: Any update on this?